# Can't enter float numbers after first time(after calculating subtotal in for each row) in datagridview cells C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagirdview in C# you enter price and quantity of the product it automatically calculates subtotal of that product, I have modified the cell for the price to enter integer and float number, and cell to enter integer and float numbers. before calculating the subtotal user can perfectly write float cell for the quantity to only enter integer numbers, but after it calculated the subtotal for that row, it doesn't allow you to enter float numbers, it only allows integer numbers. I have looked at many source but couldn't find a solution. Please help me to fix this error I really appreciated.

here is a screenshot of the gridview
[image]
as you can see I have enter a float number in column 4 but that's before calculating the subtotal in column 8.
this is my code for entering float and integer numbers in columns

```
 private void dgvpurchase_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        if (dgvpurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 || dgvpurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5) //Desired Column
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            }
        }
        if (dgvpurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 || dgvpurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 7)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column2_KeyPress);
            }
        }
    }
    //allowing real and float numbers for price columns
    private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // allow 1 dot:
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }

    //allowing only int number of column quantity and bonuus
    private void Column2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

and this is the code for calculating subtotal for each product

```
private void CalculateAll() {
        try
        {
            total_all = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvpurchase.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dgvpurchase.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null)
                {

                }
                double price = float.Parse(dgvpurchase.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                double quantity = float.Parse(dgvpurchase.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                double subtotal = price * quantity;
                dgvpurchase.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = Math.Round(subtotal, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
                total_all += subtotal;

            }
            // total_all=Math. total_all
            txttotalall.Text = Math.Round(total_all,3,MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString();
            }
```

I have called this method inside CellEndEdit event for the datagrid view, this is the code

```
 private void dgvpurchase_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            CalculateAll();    
    }
```

please, could you please find out what is the problem I really appreciate it.

Comment: You do not state “how” the grid is originally filled. If the grid uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`, then, adding a “Expression” column to the table may make things much easier. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) … IMHO, doing this IN the grid is a last resort option, however, this will depend on how the initial data is loaded.

Comment: @JohnG thanks for your comment, the grid is filled when you scan barcode in the text field above the datagrid, when you scan the barcode a new row added to the grid with product information and after that you change the price and quantity.

Comment: There is too much missing, and column index confusion to test why the code is not working. I am curious “why” you want to use a `float` when the values look like decimals, is there some reason you do not use `decimal` for this as opposed to a `float`? Also, it is unclear “how” the grid columns are constructed. Is there a data source in the grid, or is the code manually adding the columns to the grid?

Comment: In addition, the code and the picture of the grid do not appear to match. Example in the `CalculateAll` method, on the line… `double quantity = float.Parse(dgvpurchase.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());` …? In the picture, column 6 has a value of “FEXOFAST-120”? This value is obviously going to fail the parse. The “double” value is stored in column 8? Since the column headers are of a non-English nature it is hard to tell which column represents which values.

Comment: Also, the indexes in the key press events are strange such that if the edited cell is in column 4 or 5, the code wires up the `Column1_KeyPress event`? The naming of the events is wrong or is confusing at the least. The column 1 key press event appears to be checking for numeric values and a single decimal place, but column 5 looks like a date column. This is all strange.

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it clear “which” columns are “which” values? As I suggested, if the grid uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`, much of this may be easier. However, this is secondary to the column confusion described above. Good Luck.

Comment: @JohnG thanks for your comments, sorry the grid is right to left, the interface in arabic that why you confused, I have removed the method "Column2_KeyPress", now is working fine but the problem is that I can inter point number in quantity.